# R Holt Winters Error in decompose 'no or less than 2 periods'

Tags: r, time-series

I have an R Time Series at the weekly level starting at Jan 7, 2013 and ending at May 23 2016.

I created the time series using the following code:

```
    start_date <- min(Orders_All_weekly$Week_Start)

    Orders_Weekly.ts <- ts(Orders_All_weekly$Sales, start = decimal_date(ymd(start_date)), freq = (365.25/7))

    Orders_Weekly.stl <- stl(Orders_Weekly.ts, s.window = 'periodic')
```

I am attempting to run a Holt Winters time series on these data, and I am receiving the error

```
Orders_Weekly.hw <- HoltWinters(Orders_Weekly.stl)


Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

I have seen several people post this error and the common response has been that the data did not, in fact, have at least two periods...which is necessary for this procedure.  Unless I'm completely misunderstanding the meaning of this (which is possible) I have more than the required two periods.  My data are at the weekly level, and I have 3+ years of observations.

Am I setting this up incorrectly?  Or is the error essentially saying there is no seasonality?

```
ID   Week_Start     Sales
1   2013-04-08  932662.9
3   2013-05-13 1021574.4
4   2013-05-20  913812.9
5   2013-06-17 1086239.1
7   2013-08-26  762829.3
8   2013-11-18 1085033.0
9   2013-12-02  897158.4
10  2013-12-09  776733.7
11  2013-12-23  867362.8
12  2013-02-04  666362.0
13  2013-02-18  748603.2
15  2013-07-22 1005986.7
16  2013-09-02  896582.8
17  2013-10-28  868364.8
18  2014-01-06  814648.7
19  2014-02-10  847342.4
20  2014-02-17  869374.3
21  2014-03-17  827677.6
22  2014-03-24  897462.3
23  2014-03-31  850542.4
24  2014-04-21 1139619.4
25  2014-07-28  889043.3
26  2014-08-04 1097560.6
27  2014-09-08 1029379.4
28  2014-10-13  998094.8
29  2014-11-10 1238445.9
30  2014-12-15 1204006.6
31  2014-07-14 1106800.6
32  2014-09-01  730030.8
33  2014-10-06 1085331.8
34  2014-05-05 1072926.8
35  2014-05-19  863283.7
36  2015-01-19 1095186.1
37  2015-02-02  866258.2
38  2015-02-16 1006247.0
39  2015-03-23 1214339.7
40  2015-04-20 1181482.9
41  2015-05-18 1112542.4
42  2015-06-01 1188714.7
43  2015-07-20 1216050.4
45  2015-08-17  848302.8
46  2015-08-24 1081198.9
47  2015-09-14  916539.8
48  2015-09-28  957177.8
49  2015-10-26  964467.1
50  2015-11-02 1063949.1
51  2015-01-12  879343.9
53  2015-03-09 1245047.9
55  2015-11-16  913514.4
56  2015-02-09 1108247.6
57  2015-12-28 1014929.2
58  2016-01-25  946786.3
59  2016-02-01  891230.8
60  2016-02-29 1274039.8
61  2016-03-07  847501.8
62  2016-04-04 1057844.1
64  2016-04-11 1207347.4
65  2016-04-18 1159690.4
66  2016-05-02 1394727.6
67  2016-05-23 1044129.3
68  2013-03-04 1040017.1
69  2013-03-11  984574.2
70  2013-04-15 1054174.1
72  2013-04-29  952720.1
73  2013-05-06 1000977.1
74  2013-06-03 1091743.6
75  2013-07-01  955164.8
76  2013-08-12  808803.7
77  2013-09-23  960096.4
78  2013-09-30  814014.4
79  2013-10-14  743264.9
81  2013-01-28  956396.4
84  2013-10-21  959058.5
85  2013-11-11  915108.6
90  2013-01-14  867140.6
91  2014-01-27  910063.7
92  2014-03-10  963144.2
93  2014-04-07  975789.6
95  2014-04-28 1030313.7
97  2014-05-26 1139089.3
99  2014-06-09 1077980.6
100 2014-06-30 1019326.6
101 2014-09-15  666787.6
103 2014-11-03 1059089.4
105 2014-11-24  705428.6
106 2014-12-22  889368.8
108 2014-06-23 1046989.4
110 2015-02-23 1327066.4
112 2015-04-13 1110673.9
115 2015-06-08 1177799.1
116 2015-07-06 1314697.7
118 2015-07-27 1094805.6
119 2015-08-03  882394.2
120 2015-09-21 1159233.2
121 2015-10-19 1171636.9
122 2015-11-23 1036050.9
125 2015-12-21  984050.8
128 2016-01-04 1371348.3
129 2016-01-11 1086225.4
131 2016-02-22 1077692.4
137 2013-03-18  854699.1
141 2013-05-27 1011870.1
142 2013-08-05  893878.4
143 2013-12-16  801215.2
148 2013-10-07  805962.8
150 2013-11-04  801729.8
152 2013-08-19  726361.0
155 2014-02-24  979288.7
158 2014-04-14 1006729.5
161 2014-07-07 1102600.4
162 2014-08-11  979494.5
164 2014-10-20  901047.1
166 2014-10-27 1260062.0
169 2014-12-29 1022656.2
171 2014-08-18  976136.5
175 2015-03-02  897352.6
177 2015-03-30 1059103.8
178 2015-05-11 1033694.4
179 2015-06-29 1037959.4
182 2015-09-07 1230050.6
183 2015-10-12  975898.2
185 2015-12-07 1057603.4
186 2015-12-14  953718.2
189 2015-04-06 1233091.9
190 2015-04-27 1176994.2
192 2015-01-26 1256182.6
196 2016-01-18  955919.5
197 2016-02-15  954623.5
198 2016-03-14  740724.2
199 2013-01-07  924205.2
201 2013-02-11  672150.0
202 2013-03-25  769391.5
205 2013-06-10  870971.1
206 2013-06-24 1043166.2
208 2013-07-15 1106379.4
210 2013-09-09  916382.0
215 2013-04-22  934307.5
217 2013-12-30  974004.0
219 2014-01-13  972211.2
220 2014-01-20  952294.8
221 2014-02-03  946820.6
225 2014-06-02 1182837.6
228 2014-08-25  912550.8
234 2014-03-03 1013797.0
245 2015-06-15  946565.2
246 2015-07-13 1139633.6
248 2015-08-10 1080701.8
249 2015-08-31 1052796.2
253 2015-11-30  980493.4
259 2016-03-28 1105384.2
264 2016-02-08  897832.2
267 2013-02-25  766646.8
269 2013-04-01  954419.8
281 2013-11-25  852430.6
286 2013-09-16  997656.1
290 2014-07-21 1171519.8
294 2014-09-29  804772.4
298 2014-12-01  813872.0
299 2014-12-08 1005479.1
304 2014-06-16  981782.5
312 2015-03-16 1009182.7
315 2015-05-25 1166947.6
329 2015-01-05  903062.3
337 2016-03-21 1299648.7
338 2016-04-25 1132090.1
341 2013-01-21  818799.7
364 2014-05-12 1035870.7
367 2014-09-22 1234683.8
381 2015-06-22  990619.5
383 2015-10-05 1175100.6
385 2015-11-09 1095345.9
395 2016-05-16 1121192.5
399 2016-05-09 1175343.4
407 2013-07-08 1035513.8
430 2014-11-17 1024473.3
443 2015-05-04 1063411.6
476 2013-07-29  809045.3
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76322/forecasting-using-holt-winters-technique-using-r-with-less-than-2-years-of-histo

Comment: Thanks.  I can use TBATS instead, as that sounds like a more generalized approach....  However, I'm still confused as to why this particular method didn't work, as the period requirement has been met.  Thanks for the link though...this is helpful.  I'll abandon the HoltWinters model for this dataset.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am also facing same error on a sensor data.

Comment: No. Unfortunately I did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this completely answers the question but I was able to get a result out of your data with the slightly modified code below.

Hope this helps!

One point, I first sorted the data by date, assuming this was part of your intent.

```
Orders_Sorted <- Orders_Weekly[order(Orders_Weekly$Week_Start),] # Sort by date (unless you want to keep the data out of date order for some reason)
Orders_Weekly.ts <- ts(Orders_Sorted$Sales, frequency = (365.25/7)) # Convert df to time series
Orders_Weekly.hw <- HoltWinters(x=Orders_Weekly.ts, beta = FALSE, gamma = FALSE) # Run HW
plot(Orders_Weekly.hw) # Show plot of HW output
```

This produces the plot below.

[Plot of Holt-Winters exponential smoothing of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfqK5.png)

Comment: Thanks! A few years late, but better than never!

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same error, except that I have been computing a moving average of my initial data.

Unfortunately, the `decompose()` function that `HoltWinters()` uses returns that error message if anything goes wrong, not just when there aren't enough periods. Look more closely at the data you're passing `HoltWinters()`, even if your initial data looks fine.

In your particular case, `Orders_Weekly.ts` is kind of a `ts` object, but it has seasonal, trend, remainder, and weights components. I'm not very familiar with `stl()`, but when I try `HoltWinters(Orders_Weekly.ts$time.series)`, it works just fine.

In my case, the moving average of my initial data introduced a bunch of `NA`s at the beginning of my time-series. After removing those, `HoltWinters()` worked.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to have at least two periods in your time series. The time series need to be complete-- there are two default time periods.

https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/time-series-has-no-or-less-than-2-periods-td4677519.html

Comment: As you can see in the original question, my data has 3+ periods...